# Why is $A = \{x \mid 1 < |x| < 2\}$ connected?

Tags: inequality, connectedness, absolute-value

$A$ is $(-1, -2) \cup (1, 2)$, and these are two disjoint sets whose union makes up $A$, so it fits the definition of disconnected but the book says that $A$ is a domain (it is open and connected). How is this set connected?

Comment: What space is this? $\mathbb{R}$? $\mathbb{R}^2$? The situation is very different in these two cases.

Comment: @Ian It doesn't say, but I think it is $\mathbb{R^2}$ because the entire section works in that space. But then I don't understand what this set means in $\mathbb{R^2}$ since it looks like an interval in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It isn't an interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's an annulus: it consists of the points between the circle $\{ |x|=1 \}$ and the circle $\{ |x|=2 \}$. And it is connected; for example, you can find a path between $x$ and $y$ by continuously rotating $x$ to the angle of $y$ and then scaling until you hit $y$.

Comment: @Ian I just looked up a picture of an annulus, and I don't understand why this set is circular pictorally. In $\mathbb{R^2}$, shouldn't it just be a shaded region between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, and $x = -1$ and $x = -2$?

Comment: No. If I'm understanding the problem correctly, there is slight abuse of notation here, in that $|x|$ is being used to refer to the Euclidean norm of the vector $x$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, that makes more sense now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $\{{\bf x} \in \Bbb R^2 \mid 1 < \|{\bf x}\| < 2\}$ is connected because it is path-connected. You can make a path between two points there using polar coordinates, for example.

The set $\{ x \in \Bbb R \mid 1 < |x| < 2\}$ is indeed $(-2,-1)\cup (1,2)$, so it is disconnected.

Comment: (+1) Or the annulus is the image of a rectangle (convex, hence connected) under a continuous map (polar coordinates). :)

Comment: It is an equally easy way to think, this one. Nice.